# How to execute shell "pm" commands within TWRP

Tags: android, package, adb, recovery

Samsung Galaxy S5 6.0.1 (stock) is rooted and is booted to TWRP and successfully accessed via adb v1.0.39.  Attempting to execute a package manager ("pm") command using "adb shell pm..." or from the shell prompt itself generates this message:

> CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE: library "libqc-opt.so" not found
>   page record for 0xb6f5700c was not found (block_size=16)

On the S5, "libqc-opt.so" is found only in /system/vendor/lib.  Most of the files in vendor/lib directory are .so type files with execute permission reset.  So I assume that is the problem.  As these are .so files, I am not able to set the execute permission.  Should the required library also be found in the Android Platform Tools, which includes adb?  Or does Marshmallow simply disable pm functionality?  Or is pm functionality only available when booted into Marshmallow and not when booted into recovery?

Any assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: [FAQ on how to question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
and [Make it Minimal, Complete and Verfiable Example(MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

pm functionality is available when booted into the ROM and not when booted into recovery. You are right about this. Though it can be enabled in recovery after a laborious process.